# Parsing JSON array with PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, api

I'm having issues returning specific data from an API query with PowerShell. I'm making a simple API call to grab a user which works great.

```
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -Method GET -Headers $Headers
$Response
```

The call returns the following.

```
Total Sum   Users         Groups
----- ----- -----         ------
    1     1 @{123456789=} @{Test Users=System.Object[]; Global Users=System.Object[]...
```

$Response.Users returns the following

```
123456789
---------
@{name= Test Case; fullname=Test Tester Case; office=Area 51;....
```

The issue is the number "123456789" is a unique identifier that changes with every user. In order to pull the needed data from each user I need to be able to parse and grab just that number.

Here is the JSON output from $Response.Users

```
{
    "123456789": {
      "name": "Test Case",
      "fullname": "Tester Test Case",
      "office": "Area 51",
      "country": "United States",
      "groups": [
        "Test Users",
        "Global Users",
        "Test OU"     
      ]
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: We could easily help you if you post the actual JSON you are getting from the request. Please also provide the desired output you want to have.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for the response. I have added the JSON output to the original post. I'm looking to return just the first string , 123456789. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the name of the **note property** using the default powershell property `PsObject` and retrieve the name of it:

```
$json = 
@'
{
    "123456789": {
      "name": "Test Case",
      "fullname": "Tester Test Case",
      "office": "Area 51",
      "country": "United States",
      "groups": [
        "Test Users",
        "Global Users",
        "Test OU"     
      ]
    }
}
'@


$json | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object {$_.PsObject.Properties.Name}
```

Or in your case:

```
$Response.Users | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object {$_.PsObject.Properties.Name}
```

Should do the trick ;-)